# React js form response issue

Tags: reactjs

I am a newbie to react and redux. I want to make a ajax call using  put method and get the response.

Here is my code :

**actions/index.jsx**

```
export  function change_pwd_details(data) {
        var hash_token ='Token '+ localStorage.getItem('usertoken');
        return function(dispatch) {
            axios.put(CHANGE_PASSWORD_API,
                    {headers:{'Authorization': hash_token,
                         'Content-Type' : "application/json"
                    }},
                    data :data)
                .then(res => {
                    var pwd_response = res;
                    dispatch(chnge_pwd_repsonse(pwd_response));
                            });

                        };
                    }

    export const chnge_pwd_repsonse = (response) =>
    ({
            type:CHANGE_PASSWORD_API_SUCCESS,
            payload: response
    })
```

As I am calling ajax call using put method and the data I am passing and token is correct but it shows me unauthorized.
As the change_pwd_details function is used to get the details of password  from the form and pass to above function as data .

The problem is I am not getting the response,dont know what the issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Did you inspected the error on your Browser's console/developer tools?

Comment: unauthorised arror,but i passed the token and data correctly!